# Better to choose SoundPool or MediaPlayer in Android?

Tags: java, android, file, audio, button

I am currently trying to make an app where there are buttons that trigger audio files, but these audio files are selected by the user, via a file browser activity. I have heard that MediaPlayer has latency issues and such, but SoundPool has memory limitations?

Also, can I let the user set the audio file by returning a string from the File Browser(selected item) and use it for the path of the audio API, which ever one it is?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AudioTrack, SoundPool or MediaPlayer Which Should I use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527134/audiotrack-soundpool-or-mediaplayer-which-should-i-use)

Answer (score 4):

`SoundPool` is faster than `MediaPlayer` but it has its own limitations.

`SoundPool` is used for small sounds like the ones that you can use in your `onClick()` method so that it can make a click sound every time user click anywhere because these files are pre-loaded in the memory which doesn't let the CPU suffer for its deeds and that is why `SoundPool` is faster than `MediaPlayer`. Also, it can manage the number of audio streams rendered at once.

`MediaPlayer` is used for such cases in which user have access to the playback options like play, pause, seek, start etc. Also, commonly for long length audio `MediaPlayer` is good as you cannot load long length audio in the memory beforehand. You can also use `MediaPlayer` to play the audio over internet (it would be useful if you are planning to do it for future release).

And in your case user is allowed to play audio from a file browser activity, I suggest you go for `MediaPlayer`.

Answer (score 3):

`SoundPool` is faster if you are trying to play already loaded files. as it takes lil more time to load files and file should be smaller for better performance.

But in your case it seems user chooses files to play from `FileBrowser`, and file size will differ, so the loading time. Go for `MediaPlayer` instead.

Comment: That is my understanding as well, `SoundPool` is really for things like games where you can store many sound effects compressed in the apk but not have to deal with delay decompressing after loading. `SoundPool` also gives you the ability to change to rate of play which is nice for sound effects.

Comment: yeah, and better thing with soundPool is you can load sounds at once dont need to load everytime you gonna play. MediaPlayer is just opposite. And in OP's case MediaPlayer is perfect.

Comment: What about issues with MediaPlayer lag between button presses and the actual playing of the file?

Comment: This will always happen, since the stream needs to be loaded even if it is local. You should make a ui progress spinner to let the user know it is loading and add a `OnPreparedListener` to your `MediaPlayer` and when it is called remove the progress spinner.