# How Can I Get a Audio File And Play It in Android

Tags: android

how can i get a Audio file and Run it from any path in Android ??

any one help me please

I'm beginner
thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you mean by "any path"? Have you ever programmed anything before?

Comment: Fro where you want to get the file? And, yes supporting @MaxLeske comment too. B/w I will suggest - 

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

as OP is a beginner in Android.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you are looking for. Check this post: [AudioTrack, SoundPool or MediaPlayer Which Should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527134/audiotrack-soundpool-or-mediaplayer-which-should-i-use)

Then, if you want to use a SoundPool:

**Step 1:** create a SoundPool

```
SoundPool mSoundPool = new SoundPool(numMaxStreams, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
```

**Step 2:** create a folder on your asset with your sounds (for example folder called music)

**Step 3:** load a sound:

```
Integer mySound = mSoundPool.load(getActivity(), R.music.mySound, 1);
```

**Step 4:** play a sound

```
AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int volume = mgr.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

mSoundPool .play(mySound, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1.0f);
```

Comment: Saved me the hassle! :D I had to explain this to the OP. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
//set up MediaPlayer     
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();     
try { 
      mp.setDataSource("/path/to/file");
      mp.prepare();
      mp.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Like so!

Comment: i need to get the path for the file :D

Comment: It depends on where you are looking for

Comment: i make application tell the user to choose his song and the application will play it 
how can i make the choice for song ??

Comment: Well then you have to look into `MediaStore`.