# NativeAudioService use with several audio files

Tags: android, javafx, android-mediaplayer, soundpool, javafxports

About Android, I use the NativeAudioService, now. That works fine with my smartphone. I have tested it with a single audio file, as mentioned in the example defined in [javafxports how to call android native Media Player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38419634/javafxports-how-to-call-android-native-media-player).

**Question 1** (Solved)

Now, if I want to listen several sounds (several files) with this service, how can I do? The example includes an explicit and single audio filename ("audio.mp3") in the `AndroidNativeAudio` class and the service does not accept any parameter as an audio filename:

```
service = (NativeAudioService)
Class.forName("com.gluonhq.nativeaudio.AndroidNativeAudio").newInstance();
```

**Question2** (Solved)

There are four methods about native audio service (play, stop, pause, resume). They work fine. But `MediaPlayer` class also provides other methods like `setCycleCount`, `setVolume` and `setAutoPlay`. Are there some extensions of this `AndroidNativeAudio` class that provide them too?

---

My solution for solving these two questions is:

- In AndroidNativeAudio class, create the attributes (ex.: nbCyclesCount, audioLevel) .Then, modify its play method for taking into account the nbCyclesCount. And create a setAudioLevel method.
- At the end, when the service (instance of AndroidNativeAudio ) is prepared, assign these attributes before playing it.

**Question3** (To solve)

It remains a BIG problem of the play method (in AndroidNativeAudio class), it is not possible to hear two sounds at the same time (simultaneously) by:

- creating an instance 1 for a sound1
- creating an instance 2 for a sound2

Sound1 is heard until Sound2 is created. After, only Sound2 is heard.

Is it due to the number of codec instances of my phone, as mentioned in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release() ?

How to simultaneously hear several sounds in an android?
The SoundPool class seems to be a solution? Already used in Smartphones games?

See the answer in:
[AudioTrack, SoundPool or MediaPlayer Which Should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527134/audiotrack-soundpool-or-mediaplayer-which-should-i-use/18548242#18548242)

THE SOLUTION:
I use the AndroidNativeAudio class and NativeAudioService interface. I have tested it on Android: it works fine with at least 5 simultaneous sounds on my phone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AudioTrack, SoundPool or MediaPlayer Which Should I use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527134/audiotrack-soundpool-or-mediaplayer-which-should-i-use)

Comment: You could possibly just create your own interface and there create as many Media Player instances (native Android, I mean) and true them. But I guess the default API from gluon charm down does not provide them.